# Swapping the default blog and shop sections in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, woothemes

I have installed the latest version of `Wordpress`. I then installed the latestest version of `Woocommerce`.

When my website loads up it displays the blogs on `www.example.com` and the shop products on `www.example.com/shop`. This seems to be the default configuration for these 2 setups.

However, my main site is a shop and not a blog. The blogging part is extra. So what I would like to see is the shop on `www.example.com`, and everything related to shop under this URL structure, and the blogging part I would like to see under `www.example.com/blog` and everything related to blogging I need under this URL structure.

I'm not sure how to "switch" the 2 URLs around? All that I did was create a Blog page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your Wordpress admin area go to 'Settings' > 'Reading'. There you will see a section called 'Front page displays', set Front page to your main shop page, and your Posts page to your new Blog page.